# Задача на Delphi (Тестирование)

Tags: delphi

В общем так, есть файл откуда берутся данные db.txt содержимым

```
1 Бла1 Бла2 Бла3
2 Бла6 Бла5 Бла4
3 Бла7 Бла8 Бла9
4 Бла12 Бла11 Бла10
```

И к каждому номеру есть своя картинка. 
Номер, понятно ID вопроса, а Бла* правильные ответы.
Нажимаю на кнопку старт. Генерирую случайное число v:=Random(3)+1 от 1 до 4
Вывожу картинку соответственно номеру Img.Picture.LoadFromFile('img/img_'+v+'.jpg');
Так же рядом с картинкой есть 3 поля ввода текста, куда должны вводится правильные ответы.
Итак, моя задача.
Получить случайное число, открыть файл и найти там строку с этим числом, получить соответствующие ответы, потом сравнить их с введёнными значениями в поля ввода текста.
По-возможности, уже использованное число, исключить из употребления. Т.е. если было сгенерировано число 3, и получен ответ, чтоб число 3 в след. раз игнорировалось, а выводилось то чего ещё не было.
Вооот. Прошу помощи!
Вот мой листинг:

```
v:=Random(3)+1; //Получаем случайное число
Img.Picture.LoadFromFile('img/img_'+v+'.jpg'); //Выводим соответствующую картинку
AssignFile(fdb,'db.txt'); reset(fdb); //Открываем файл для чтения
read(fdb,vid,otv1,otv2,otv3); //Назначаем переменные
{Здесь какой-то код, который ищет строку с номером V}
```

Answer (score 1):

К ответу Dex - прошу прощения за некомпетентность (конкретно с РСЛОС - см.вики - не разбирался), однако, псевдослучайные последовательности, вообще говоря, отнюдь НЕ ГАРАНТИРУЮТ НЕПОВТОРЯЕМОСТИ генерируемых значений.

как вариант решения проблемы повторения вопроса - для того чтобы избежать хранения в памяти всех вопросов одновременно как структур и т.п. и исключить появление повторов, создать массив (вектор) из n значений (n - число вопросов, значения - от 1 до n или от 0 до n-1, как удобнее), воспользоваться ЛЮБЫМ генератором псевдослучайных последовательностей (в том числе и "встроенным" в Делфи (вроде есть?)). Далее так (предполагается индексация 1-n):

1. Вызвать генератор значений от 1 до n. Получим индекс m.
2. Выбрать номер вопроса ИЗ ЯЧЕЙКИ С ИНДЕКСОМ m (пусть будет k).
3. Поместить значение ИЗ ЯЧЕЙКИ С ИНДЕКСОМ n в ячейку с индексом m.
4. Уменьшить n на 1.
5. Отобразить k-тый вопрос.
6. Если n > 0 то вернуться к шагу 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Грузите сразу файл в память
2. Ведите список "прозвучавших вопросов", заносите туда индексы и проверяйте каждый раз при генерации нового не было ли такого вопроса уже.
3. Можно поступить проще в зависимости от количества вопросов можно воспользоваться псевдослучайной последовательностью (для числа 7 их 3 штуки разных). В таком случае не нужен список "прозвучавших вопросов", всегда можно продолжить тест с места остановки, повторение не возможно, пока не будет пройден весь цикл.

**UPD**

Для (1) Грузите в структуру (например в список, можно еще отсортировать, если вопросы не по порядку)
Для (2) тут вариантов реализации масса, например:

1. Загрузили все в память (как сказано в 1), знаете количество вопросов
2. Генерируете число от (количества вопросов), берете картинку, бла бла бла
3. Удаляете вопрос из списка
4. Для последующего вопроса генератор уже от (количество вопросов - 1)
5. И так далее

Для (3) [английская вики](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Some_polynomials_for_maximal_LFSRs) или [русская вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регистр_сдвига_с_линейной_обратной_связью)

Comment: 1. Что значит грузить СРАЗУ файл в память?
2. С этим решением я знаком, но меня интересуют подробности 3 способа. Расскажите подробнее о нём пожалуйста!

Comment: см. upd